# Insert at once multi dimensional values in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

values are like:

```
<?php
$imp_name_contact = Array
(
    [0] => p1
    [1] => +91786555
)
Array
(
    [0] => p3
    [1] => +9123457788
)
Array
(
    [0] => p2
    [1] => +91454543
);

for ($i=0; $i < count($imp_name_contact) ; $i++) {
    if(empty($imp_name_contact['0'])) {
        $imp_name_contact['0'] = '##';
    }
    $data = array('name' => $imp_name_contact['0'], 'contact' => $imp_name_contact['1'], 'added_date_time' => $currentDateTime, 'user_id' => $user_id );
    $query = $this->db->insert("tbl_name", $data);
    $this->db->insert_id();
}
?>
```

but the problem is it is inserting same values twice. what is the wrong?
is it possible to use insert_batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prepare an array, for example,  in such way

```
$string = 'aabc-+9123457788,fsfs-989776655';
$imp_name_contact = explode(',', $string);
foreach($imp_name_contact as &$i) 
    $i = explode('-', $i);

$data = [];
foreach($imp_name_contact as $i) {
    if(empty($i['0'])) {
        $i['0'] = '##';
    }
    $data[] = array('name' => $i['0'], 
              'contact' => $i['1'], 
              'added_date_time' => $currentDateTime, 
              'user_id' => $user_id );
}
```

and now you can use `insert_batch`

[demo](https://eval.in/586897)

Comment: how to do that? because that array is dynamically creted

Comment: actually the value are like:
aabc-+9123457788,fsfs-989776655
then i am exploding those values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114380/discussion-between-pathik-vejani-and-splash58).

Comment: $imp_name_contact = explode('-', $imp_name_contact);

Comment: yes, i can see that, but now what? how can i make it same yours one

Comment: I called it after foreach loop is completed

Comment: yes it is not inseting values right way.. it is just instreting first character only

Comment: it is the array as I posted

Comment: main array is like:
Array
(
    [0] => aa-+91786555
    [1] => bb-+9123457788
    [2] => cc-989776655
)
now how can i insert those values?

Comment: I got the same format but now last record doe not insert into database instead of that second last records inserted twice

Comment: suppose string is: aa-+91786555,bb-+9123457788,cc-989776655.. then it don't insert cc data. but inserting bb twice

Comment: change string in demolink and watch result

Comment: there is right, and also in my code i am getting right output, but some how it is not inserting last one value and inserting 2nd last twice. can you say why?

Comment: I do not even hypotheses. If the array is correct, it can not be so strange inserted to DB

Comment: it worked!, just it was overwrtting $i value, i changed the name of another $i var to $ii and it worked!!